# Is it possible to call a DynamicMethod from MethodBuilder/ConstructorBuilder

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, dynamicmethod

I have an ILGenerator created from ConstructorBuilder, and I want to create and call a DynamicMethod with it but I get an InvalidOperationException - 
Unable to import a global method or field from a different module.

```
var constructorBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(...);
var ilGenFromCtor = constructorBuilder.GetILGenerator();
.
.
.
var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("Name", ReturnType, Type.EmptyTypes, true);
var ilGenFromDynamicMethod = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
.
.
var @delegate = dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate();

ilGenFromCtor.Emit(OpCodes.Call, @delegate.Method);

--Or

ilGenFromCtor.Emit(OpCodes.Call, dynamicMethod);

10x
```

Comment: Have you tried invoking the delegate (calling its `Invoke()` method)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're actually defining an entire, complete assembly at runtime, you're going to have to declare the method somewhere within the assembly (perhaps within the class from which you got the `ConstructorBuilder`) by using one of the overloads of [`TypeBuilder.DefineMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf36892y.aspx) and the [`MethodBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.methodbuilder.aspx) instance it returns. `DynamicMethod` objects are handled entirely differently by the .NET runtime than what `Reflection.Emit` uses. Once you've defined your method using the `MethodBuilder`, you can use it as your second parameter to `ILGenerator.Emit`.